# Correct typing for postponed value assignment

Tags: typescript

How to correctly type variables which are undefined or null from the beginning but they are definitely assigned later and without using non-null-assertion "!".

Very simplified reproduction of a problem:

```
function example(): number {
  let x: null | number = null;

  function doStuff(n: number) {
    x = n;
  } 

  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    doStuff(1);
  } else {
    doStuff(2);
  }

  return x;
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgEoAuRMETAI2QCdEBvAKEUXykVTIt10QB9ylGvQC8Q3gG4mLRKEiwEiACZwAylBDBgBMN2F0ijWa1SJxYaawC%20iGaxg6AsuigALAHS10YVZmKIAHyIAAweAKxGzKysqhpaOgCMRFaItsi4AM7IxjEq6praBABMKbLW9oi0yJq0SKjS1kA)

My real case looks more like this:

```
export function useElection(
    id: string | Ref<string>,
): {
   loading: Ref<boolean>, 
   error: Ref<any>,
   election: ComputedRef<Election>,
} {
    const fetchCtrl: Ref<ReturnType<FetchElection> | null> = ref(null);

    const store = useElectionsStore();
    const election: ComputedRef<Election> = computed(
        () => store.electionById(unref(id))
    );

    function doFetch() {
        fetchCtrl.value = (store.fetchElection as FetchElection)(unref(id), includingCandidates, autoUpdateInterval);
    }

    if (isRef(id)) {
        watchEffect(doFetch)
      } else {
        // otherwise, just fetch once
        // and avoid the overhead of a watcher
        doFetch();
      }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
    return {...fetchCtrl.value!, election };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in the way typescript does control flow analysis (CFA). As described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), CFA does not cross function boundaries, so the assignment in the function will not be taken into account when trying to figure out types.

Since your real example constrains a wrapper object, you could use a custom type assertion to get this to type check.

```
type Ref<T> = { value: T }
function example(): number {
  let x: Ref<null | number> = { value : null };

  function doStuff(p: Ref<null | number>, n: number): asserts p is Ref<number>{
    p.value = n;
  } 

  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    doStuff(x, 1);
  } else {
    doStuff(x, 2);
  }

  return x.value; // number now
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAeAKgPigXigbygNwEMAbAVwgC4pkoBfAKHhIDsBjYASwHsmoIAPAgFswRCAAoAlJSYlBAIwgAnHHShRRwKH0pwkMokSgAfKDPlL0WXIVLRpJA7QDcdVVEasO3KABNOAZWASeHgxMB0ERH1DEzMFRVQAGlN7c0UpKAIAZyylYCyoMCh2At0o2XjUbDc1MAA6GzJMUxc1GihXNXZQgFkCYAALOsUCJj9BSSh0AAY6gFYJFTU1P0Dg0L5kgEYJVtpeIlyl5dWgkLFNqAAmXbd6N0UIIMUePgbiMhcaIA)

The custom type assertion implementation is not actually checked by TS, so you are responsible for the implementation, so not sure this is much better than a simple type assertion when you return.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing better insight whats happening there, I will be further thinking about it more later, because now I can, as you identify the issue for me, many thanks again 